# Passing string arguments from TeX to a Lua function?

Tags: luatex

There is an extra space after "abbr" and "printsorted" does not work.
What's my mistake?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\addtosorten#1#2{%
    \directlua{%
    tblen=tblen or {}%
    table.insert(tblen, {abbr="\luaescapestring{#1}", desc="\luaescapestring{#2}"})
}
}
\newcommand{\keyen}[2]{#1\addtosorten{#1}{#2}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\printsorted{%
    \directlua{%
    tblen=tblen or {}
    table.sort(tblen)
    for i,n in ipairs(tblen) do
        tex.print("\string\\printkw{" .. n.abbr .. "}{" .. n.desc .. "}")
    end
}}

\newcommand\printkw[2]{\textbf{#1}~-- #2.\\}

\newcommand{\placekeywordshere}{%
    \typeout{KW: NOW SHOWING}
    \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{3pt}
            
    \noindent\printsorted
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\keyen{LED}{Light emitting diode}.

\keyen{FET}{Field effect transistor}.

\keyen{SCADA}{Supervisory control and data acquisition}.

\placekeywordshere
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is more of a Lua programming question than a TeX question. Look at the console to view the error message → `attempt to compare two table values
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'table.sort'
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
`

Comment: @user202729. Everything seems to work in Lua.

Comment: "seem to" how? What do you want to sort the table by anyway?

Comment: My mistake: table.sort(tblen, function (a,b) return (a.abbr < b.abbr) end) !!!!
Thanks, @user202729

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usual problem: an unprotected endline. Don't use `\\` to end paragraphs, unless you're inside the scope of `\raggedright`, for instance in `flushleft`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand\addtosorten[2]{%
    \directlua{%
      tblen=tblen or {}%
      table.insert(tblen, {abbr="\luaescapestring{#1}", desc="\luaescapestring{#2}"})
    }% <--- HERE!
}
\newcommand{\keyen}[2]{#1\addtosorten{#1}{#2}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand\printsorted{%
    \directlua{%
    tblen=tblen or {}
    %table.sort(tblen)
    table.sort(tblen, function (a,b) return (a.abbr < b.abbr) end)
    for i,n in ipairs(tblen) do
        tex.print("\string\\printkw{" .. n.abbr .. "}{" .. n.desc .. "}")
    end
}}
\newcommand\printkw[2]{\textbf{#1}~-- #2.\\}

\newcommand{\placekeywordshere}{%
    \typeout{KW: NOW SHOWING}
    \begin{flushleft}
    \rule{\textwidth}{3pt}\\
    \printsorted
    \end{flushleft}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\keyen{LED}{Light emitting diode}.

\keyen{FET}{Field effect transistor}.

\keyen{SCADA}{Supervisory control and data acquisition}.

\placekeywordshere
\end{document}
```

[image]